# Simple question about finding the inverse function from $R^{1}$ into $R^{2}$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I'm stuck on computing the inverse for some simple functions; e.g.,

> Consider the following two functions,
>
> 1. $f(t) := [\cos(t), \; \sin(t)]$ with $t \in (-\pi, \pi)$
> 2. $g(x) := [x, \; x^2]$ for $x \in [0, \infty)$

I want to find the corresponding $f^{-1}$ and $g^{-1}$.

Here is my thinking: I first need to make sure the inverse exists, so go to check one-to-one property then onto property. Assume $t,s \in (-\pi, \pi)$, observe $$f(s)=f(t) \Rightarrow [\cos(t)-\cos(s), \; \sin(t)-\sin(s)]=0 \Rightarrow t=s$$ Hence, $f$ is one-to-one.  then I stuck to show its is onto, and fail to find its inverse.

Same situation for $g$.

Thank you.

Comment: You are stuck showing it's onto because it's not even close to onto; neither of these are. While there are continuous injections $[0,1] \to [0,1]^2$, and continuous surjections $[0,1] \to [0,1]^2$, there are no continuous *bijections* $[0,1] \to [0,1]^2$.

Comment: Neither of these functions are onto $\mathbb R^2$, so that would explain why you are stuck proving that they are. For instance, $(1,2) \notin g[[0,\infty)]$ since $1^2 \neq 2$. However, you can define $f^{-1}$ and $g^{-1}$ on the images of $f$ and $g$, respectively.

Comment: Thank you @Alqatrkapa, now I start considering, say $f$ maps from $(-\pi,\pi) \to f(-\pi,\pi)$; now, we could find $f^-1$ (since already onto) but I still stuck to find the explicit form of $f^-1$..

Answer (score 1):

Neither $f$ nor $g$ are onto in $R^2$. For example, there is no $t$
s.t. $f\left(t\right)=\left(0,0\right)$. Similarly, there is no $t$
s.t. $g\left(t\right)=\left(0,1\right)$.

Let $h:A\rightarrow B$. Let 
$$
\text{range}\left(h\right)\equiv h\left(A\right)\equiv\left\{ b\in B:h\left(a\right)=b\right\} 
$$
While $h$ may or may not be onto, note that
$\hat{h}:A\rightarrow\text{range}\left(h\right)$ with $\hat{h}\left(a\right)=h\left(a\right)$
for all $a\in A$ is always onto.

If, for example, you consider $\hat{g}:\left[0,\infty\right)\rightarrow\text{range}\left(g\right)$
with $\hat{g}\left(t\right)=g\left(t\right)$, we can find the inverse
$\hat{g}^{-1}$. This inverse is given by $\hat{g}^{-1}\left(\mathbf{y}\right)=y_{1}$.

Try doing the same thing with $f$. Be careful with $\arccos$ or $\arcsin$; make sure your results map back to $\left(-\pi,\pi\right)$.

Comment: Thank you @par, I was wondering if you can show me how to do for the $f$ case (assume $f: (-\pi, \pi) \to f(-\pi,\pi)$) ? .

Comment: I think I have given you enough hints to proceed. Perhaps think about it for a while, as this seems like an assignment question.

Answer (score 0):

it helps to think the functions geometrically. a way to look at $f$ is treat $t$ as the signed arc length on the unit circle taking the origin at $(1,0)$ and counter clockwise as the positive direction. the function maps the arc length $t$ to the cartesian coordinates of the terminal point on the unit circle of length $t.$ to find the inverse function, that is given $x$ and $y$ find $t.$ $t$ has the same sign as $y$ and $\cos t = x$ so $$f^{-1}(x,y) = t = sgn(y)\arccos (x).$$